# How to pick one UILabel out of 64

Tags: xcode

Basically how to do the following but for 64 labels:

```
int lblInt = arc4random() % 64
if (lblInt == 0) {
    lbl.text = @"Letter";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use an array instead?

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
    [arr addObject:lbl];
    [someSuperview addSubview:lbl];
    [lbl release];
}
```

Then you could make each label display a random letter using this code:

```
for (UILabel *lbl in arr) {
    int r = arc4random() % 64;
    if (r < 26) {
        lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 'a' + r];
    } else if (r < 52) {
        lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 'A' + r - 26];
    } else if (r < 62) {
        lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", '0' + r - 52];
    } else {
        // whatever the last two characters should be
    }
}
```